# why didn't the brownie bake when cheesecake was put on top?

Tags: baking

I found a recipe for Cookies and Cream Brownies.  First time I made them they were great, in a 9x13 aluminum pan.  Second time, I used an aluminum foil-type pan that you take to potlucks, and while the cheesecake was completely baked on the top, there was raw brownie batter on the bottom, giving the appearance of a fudge sauce on the bottom.  It was really weird, that it didn't even partially bake.  Does this happen when using the foil-type pans?  That's all I can think of.  The directions do not say to bake the brownie first then put the cheesecake on top and bake more...you bake at one time.

Comment: Was the foil dish directly on the oven shelf, or was it on a baking sheet? I always do the latter (preheating the baking sheet at least partially) when cooking in foil,  for support as foil dishes aren't all that strong.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can matter is that darker pans often absorb more heat (from  radiative heating). So if your 9x13 pan is dark-bottomed (e.g., nonstick, or darkened from years of use) it'll run hotter than a shiny foil pan. I'd be surprised for that to result in *raw*, though, normally its just more or less browning.

If you put a baking sheet under the foil pan, that could also function as an insulator, especially if its a steel pan instead of aluminum.

I'd guess instead some other "human error" thing happened: measured and ingredient incorrectly, left something out, added something twice, set the oven temperature (or mode!) wrong, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've already narrowed it down. The foil pan does not conduct heat as well as the aluminum pan, which is causing the bottom to go uncooked.

Comment: Foil *is* aluminium, so the heat conduction is the same. If there were stripes of cooked batter over the wires of the oven shelf you might have a point, and this could probably be avoided by placing the foil dish on a baking sheet if that wasn't already done (preheat the baking sheet)

Comment: @ChrisH foil is significantly thinner than the pan, thus is less able to conduct heat.

Comment: @Catija It's less able to conduct heat *laterally* hence my comment about stripes.  It's *more* able to conduct heat from one face to the other, precisely because it's thinner